# How can I make bash completion (tab auto-complete) match a particular command first?

Tags: bash, auto-completion

I develop using Python on Ubuntu and so I use the `workon` command (from `virtualenvwrapper`) a lot to switch virtualenvs.

Previously, `workon` was the first tab-completion match for "wo", so I could type <kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd> to match it.  But now on Ubuntu 16.04 this is matching to `word-list-compress` instead, so I need to type  <kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd> instead.

How can I remove `word-list-compress` from the tab completion search, or otherwise make `workon` the first match for <kbd>w</kbd>,<kbd>o</kbd>,<kbd>tab</kbd>?

Note - `workon` itself has auto-complete support (tab to choose between virtualenvs).

Comment: Curious: why don't you alias it to `wo` and just `wo` `Enter`?

Comment: @muru good question - workon has autocomplete support, I don't think aliasing will support that.

Comment: There is a -n option in the autocompletion script to exclude patterns, but I am not sure on how to modify the calling to the completion. Probably just a modification in `.bashrc` would work...

Comment: @therefromhere a better shell (like zsh) supports autocompletion with aliases. Or you could configure tab to cycle in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

From [this blog](https://blog.onetechnical.com/2012/06/19/disable-bash-autocompletion-on-ubunt/) it should be sufficient to do

```
complete -r word-list-compress
```

in order to remove it from the completion list.

**I do not know** (yet) **how to revert it**, so I did not try it myself.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already, it didn't work - I think it's completing word-list-compress since it's found in /use/bin , so there's not a specific completion rule defined for it.